# User Avatars on My Relationships: friends Block

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I have read several tutorials about doing this through views but I was wondering if it is possible to modify the block created out of the box by user relationships without having to create a view.

Am using the following version for the module; 
-UR 7.x-1.0-alpha4

Comment: It's possible, but more work and requires more knowledge of Drupal and PHP.  What exactly are you trying to do, and why won't Views work for you?

Comment: Views would work. I just thought it might be a bit harder than modifying a few lines of PHP in the block. If you have a 'views' receipt, post it as an answer and and i'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy /user_relationships/user_relationship_blocks/templates/user_relationships-block.tpl.php to your custom theme's directory and you can make any modifications you want from there.

Make sure **NOT** to edit that in place. You don't want to end up in a situation where your modifications are scattered all over different module folders.